# c++ boost MPI & threading -  serialize errors: Address not mapped

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, mpi, boost-mpi

I'm stumped.  `all_gather` works for primitives (e.g. `int`) but fails even for simple STL containers.  valgrind claims that the container was not allocated/initialized, but that doesn't seem right.

In summary:

- I do some multi-threading with openMP, then rejoin threads.
- In serial, I try to `all_gather` a simple `std::map` using `boost::mpi::all_gather.  The MPI ranks are *not* the threads. (There are 2 MPI ranks, and each MPI rank has 4 threads).
- Then I intend to do some more (isolated) multi-threading.

It seems so straightforward... what could possibly be going on here?

main.cpp

```
#include <openmpi/mpi.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>    
#include "globals.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{        

    int provided_MPI;
    MPI_Init_thread(&argc, &argv, MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE, &provided_MPI );

    boost::mpi::environment my_boost_mpi_env(argc, argv);
    boost::mpi::communicator world_MPI_boost;        
    world_MPI_boost_ptr = &world_MPI_boost;
        // ^^^ global variable of type   boost::mpi::communicator *

    perform_complete_variable_elimination_schedule();
    //...

}
```

Conn_Comp.cpp

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>    
#include <boost/mpi/collectives.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>

#include "globals.h"

...

void perform_complete_variable_elimination_schedule()
{

    // isolated work in parallel using OpenMP
    #pragma omp parallel
    { 
    //work
    }    

    // SERIAL REGION (with respect to threading).

    std::map<uint,uint> my_map;
    std::vector< std::map<uint,uint> >   vec_of_my_maps;

    boost::mpi::all_gather<    std::map<uint,uint>    >
                     (*world_MPI_boost_ptr,
                      my_map,
                      vec_of_my_maps);  //  <--- line 293 (referenced by valgrind)


    // more isolated work in parallel using OpenMP
    #pragma omp parallel
    { 
    //work
    }

}
```

valgrind complains that the `vector` of `map`  results in an invalid read.  But this `vector` was created immediately preceding the `all_gather` call - so it is obviously in scope and not in parallel-threaded region.
selected valgrind error output:

```
==12665== Use of uninitialised value of size 4
==12665==    at 0x41C8D7A: boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::get_library_version() const (basic_iarchive.cpp:575)
==12665==    by 0x41C92C6: boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::load_object(void*, boost::archive::detail::basic_iserializer const&) (basic_iarchive.cpp:399)
==12665==    by 0x80F5696: void boost::mpi::all_gather<std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned int> > > >(boost::mpi::communicator const&, std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned int> > > const&, std::vector<std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned int> > > > >&) (iserializer.hpp:387)
==12665==    by 0x80DEC83: Conn_Comp::perform_complete_variable_elimination_schedule() (Conn_Comp.cpp:**293**)
==12665==    by 0x80C840A: main (main.cpp:695)
==12665== 
==12665== Invalid read of size 2
==12665==    at 0x41C8D7A: boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::get_library_version() const (basic_iarchive.cpp:575)
==12665==    by 0x41C92C6: boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive::load_object(void*, boost::archive::detail::basic_iserializer const&) (basic_iarchive.cpp:399)
==12665==    by 0x80F5696: void boost::mpi::all_gather<std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned int> > > >(boost::mpi::communicator const&, std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned int> > > const&, std::vector<std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned int> > >, std::allocator<std::map<unsigned int, unsigned int, std::less<unsigned int>, std::allocator<std::pair<unsigned int const, unsigned int> > > > >&) (iserializer.hpp:387)
==12665==    by 0x80DEC83: Conn_Comp::perform_complete_variable_elimination_schedule() (main.cpp:**293**)
==12665==    by 0x80C840A: main (main.cpp:695)
==12665==  Address 0x3580bece is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==12665== 
[drosphila:12665] *** Process received signal ***
[drosphila:12665] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[drosphila:12665] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[drosphila:12665] Failing at address: 0x3580bece
[drosphila:12665] [ 0] /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0(+0xe500) [0x44f8500]
[drosphila:12665] [ 1] /usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.42.0(_ZN5boost7archive6detail14basic_iarchive11load_objectEPvRKNS1_17basic_iserializerE+0x1b7) [0x41c92c7]
[drosphila:12665] [ 2] ./detect_NAHR(_ZN5boost3mpi10all_gatherISt3mapIjjSt4lessIjESaISt4pairIKjjEEEEEvRKNS0_12communicatorERKT_RSt6vectorISD_SaISD_EE+0x587) [0x80f5697]
[drosphila:12665] [ 3] ./detect_NAHR(_ZN9Conn_Comp46perform_complete_variable_elimination_scheduleEv+0x534) [0x80dec84]
[drosphila:12665] [ 4] ./detect_NAHR(main+0xf5b) [0x80c840b]
[drosphila:12665] [ 5] /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe6) [0x4519ca6]
[drosphila:12665] [ 6] ./detect_NAHR() [0x80c73e1]
[drosphila:12665] *** End of error message ***
```

I use MPI_Init_thread based on a recommendation from a *boost* [help page](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2010/12/64752.php).

As I said at the top, if I use a primitive (i.e. just `uint`) instead of a map, then the `all_gather` works fine.  Why should the map fail?  `boost serialize` already has methods for serializing STL containers, so that is not the problem...

Note also that the vector which will hold all of the values is automatically resized in `all_gather` (I checked the implementation for `all_gather`) to be big enough to hold everything.  regardless, even if I initialize it myself, it still fails.

Finally, even if I use a plain old array (properly allocated) e.g. `std::map<uint,uint> *`, I get the same problem.

Comment: I hope that `boost::mpi` is built on the C MPI API and not on the C++ one which is deprecated and will be dropped from MPI v3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Well, this is embarrassing.
I'm going to leave the question up in case anybody else has the same strange errors.

The problem with my code was actually in the makefile.
I forgot to link to the boost library for MPI.

incorrect makefile flags:

```
-I$(BOOST_INCLUDE)     -lboost_serialization   -lboost_mpi
```

Apparently that  line contains just enough information to allow the program to compile and run, but results in a runtime error.

Correct makefile flags:

```
-L$(BOOST_LIB) -ldl -Wl,-rpath,$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_serialization -lboost_mpi
```

(Notice the addition of the library linking flags).

Comment: How about set the boost library in the LIBRARY_PATH environment? Could you please explain the function of each flags?